# First record and last query

Tags: mysql, sql

With this query I display the year field, the first record in ASC order, and the last in DESC order.

Works well if the year field is different

example:

1960-1970

but if the field is the same

example:

1960

I see duplicate

1960 - 1960

I would only like to see once

1960

how to do?

```
$query = "(SELECT 
year as year_asc
FROM film_actor 
INNER JOIN film ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id 
INNER JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
WHERE film_actor.actor_id = $actor_id
ORDER BY year ASC
LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
year as year_desc
FROM film_actor 
INNER JOIN film ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id 
INNER JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
WHERE film_actor.actor_id = $actor_id
ORDER BY year DESC
LIMIT 1)";
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect is this? Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, ...?

Comment: `LIMIT 1` means that only 1 record is returned, so if the query returns 2 rows with `1960`, then `1960` is both the min and max years. To eliminate that duplicate, remove `ALL` from `UNION`, making the final result implicitly `DISTINCT`.

Comment: *FYI:* It it probably more efficient to specify `SELECT MIN(year)` instead of `ORDER BY year ASC LIMIT 1`

Comment: SQL for MYSQL e Php

Answer (score 1):

you may use `UNION`, rather than `UNION ALL`since `UNION` will eliminate duplicates.

Comment: other thing, how to remove the hyphen in the end? (after 1990)

`1960 - 1990 -`

Comment: this result `<?php echo $row->year_asc .'&nbsp;-'.  $row->years_desc; ?>`

Comment: @Alex . . . This answers the question you have asked here, and should be accepted.  There is no hyphen, as far as I can tell.  If you have a different question, ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  Be sure the sample data actually matches the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the minimum and maximum years, you can put them in a single query:

```
SELECT MIN(year) as min_year, MAX(year) as max_year
FROM film_actor fa JOIN
     film f
     ON fa.film_id = f.film_id JOIN
     actor a
     ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
WHERE fa.actor_id = $actor_id;
```

If you want a single column, perhaps with a hyphen, you can use:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', MIN(YEAR), NULLIF(MAX(YEAR), MIN(YEAR)))
```